# Regex - analytics filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to filter some urls using `gapi.client.analytics`. What I want to achive is to create a regex filter that covers a lot of options. The regex should keep only urls that have this structure:

`subdomain1.domain.com/some-post/`

My problem is that I have some other urls that I don't know how to exclude, like:

```
    subdomain1.domain.com/p/code/
    subdomain1.domain.com/
    subdomain1.domain.com/some-author/some-name/
    subdomain2.domain.com/some-post/
    subdomain2.domain.com/p/code/
```

I tried to use: `ga:hostname=@subdomain1.domain.com` to get links that contain only subdomain1.

I also tried: `ga:hostname=~^[^/]+/?[^/]+/?$` to get only those who have 2 `/` in url.

Unfortunately I coudn't manage to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should match URLs with exact one trailing directory

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.domain\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/$
```

or

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/$
```

to match every domain.

You can text google analytics regex on [analyticsmarket.com](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester)